# How to Get T argument in generic class and return another type in Interface

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics

I want to use this code:

```
List<U> SelectAll<T>() where T : class;
```

the problem is I want to pass T type and get U type but c# has T keyword but does not have U keyword.how I can Pass T type ad get another Type in Interface declration>

thanks

---

Sorry I post Answer here but I want show you code:
I'm writing this code:

```
interface IRepoitory<T> where T : class
{
    T CreateInstance();

    IEnumerable<U> SelectAll();
```

what can I write instead of "U"?
when I Impelement interface and I have this code:

```
IEnumerable<TResult> SelectAll<TResult>();
```

In Class that implement the interface I cant Return Any class instead of TResult
thanks

Answer (score 3):

`T` is not a keyword in C# - it's just a conventional name for a type parameter. If you want to specify multiple type parameters, you can do so very easily:

```
public static List<U> SelectAll<T, U>() where T : class
```

(It's not clear where the data's coming from or how `T` will be used here, admittedly.)

Conventionally type parameters either *are* T or *start* with T, so you might want:

```
public static List<TResult> SelectAll<TResult>() where T : class
```

If you can clarify what you're trying to do, we may be able to help more.

Comment: Thanks @Jon.I want a thing similar to Func<in T,out TResult> delegate that pass a type to it and get a TResult.

Comment: @Nima: Well you can create such a thing... but it's hard to give any more details without knowing more about the context. If you could give a short but complete example of the situation you've already got, and what you're trying to do, that would really help.

Comment: Consider I Have a table in My Database that Have 10 Columns.In SelectAll method I want to return just 6 columns.It requires that I create a class(My return Type) that cover this return type.In my repository Interface what I can write to do this and can implement it to my DAL?Thanks

Comment: @Nima: Normally you'd use an anonymous type for this... but it still isn't really clear what you're asking from a language point of view. Please provide more sample code.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static List<TResult> SelectAll<T, TResult>(T inParam) where T: class
    {
        return new List<TResult>();
    }
```

Is that you want?? If you don't know the type of result, you need to tell method compiler what type to return. This is done using `SelectAll<T, TResult>`